# How forward() method is used when it have more than one two input parameters in pytorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, tensor

Can someone tell me the concept behind the multiple parameters in `forward()` method?
Generally, the implementation of `forward()` method has two parameters

1. self
2. input

if a forward method has more than these parameters how PyTorch is using the forward method.

Let's consider this codebase:
https://github.com/bamps53/kaggle-autonomous-driving2019/blob/master/models/centernet.py
here online 236 authors have used forward method with two more parameters:

1. centers
2. return_embeddings

I am unable to find a single article that can answer my query on what condition Line 254(`return_embeddings:`) and Line 257(`if centers is not None:`) will execute. As per my knowledge forward, the method is internally called by nn module. Can someone please put some lights on this?

Answer (score 9):

The forward function is set by you. That means you can add more parameters as you wish. For example, you can add inputs as shown below

```
def forward(self, input1, input2, input3):
    x = self.layer1(input1)
    y = self.layer2(input2)
    z = self.layer3(input3)

    net = torch.cat((x,y,z),1)
     
    return net
```

Key point is that you have to control your parameters while feeding the network. Layers couldn't be fed with more than a parameter. Therefore, you need to extract features from your input one by one and concatenate with `torch.cat((x,y),1)`(1 for dimension) them.

Comment: if we can set up our own parameters than how Pytorch will come to know while calling forward function which input params it needs? is it at the time of training?
As I asked I need clarification when those two conditions will be called?

Comment: Firstly and foremost, the forward function set when you built up the network. Normally the network function called as `output = model(input)` . However, when you have multiple input network, `output = model(input1,input2)`. It's directly connected to your network implementation. If you want to use the network with mulitple parameters, you have to define your own network.

Comment: So it means input1 and input2 both are different inputs and when we train this network it should have "number of data input" is equal to the "number of parameters in forward() function. Am I correct?

Comment: So in that case from why the default value of return_embeddings=False? it should be some input I have never seen in Keras also someone giving binary value(not like tensor of binary values just a single binary value.)